# Process I/O bound co-routines in an infinite loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have an always-on video stream being processed in an infinite loop. Once a certain object is detected, a second I/O bound method (let's refer to this as FuncIO) is triggered. Ideally, only 1 of FuncIO should run at a time. Once FuncIO completes, the parent loop should continue (i.e., wait for the next trigger of FuncIO).

Here is the pseudocode:

```
def FuncIO(self):
  if self._funcio_running:
    # Only 1 instance of FuncIO should run at a time. 
    # Is this the best place to enforce this?
    return
  self._funcio_running = true
  PerformsBlockingIO()
  self._funcio_running = false
  return

def main_loop(self):
  while True:
    if detect_object():
      # Run FuncIO asynchronously
    else:
      # Performs other tasks.
```

I'm a bit new to asyncio so I would like to know if there is an existing design pattern I can use to handle this scenario.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your question, you don't leverage the advantages of asynchronous functionality with this approach, and maybe you don't even need it here.

If I didn't understand your question correctly, so there is a special lock mechanism in `asyncio`, you can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html), would be something like that:

```
async def FuncIO(self):
    await lock.acquire()
    try:
        PerformsBlockingIO()
    finally:
        lock.release()
```

Comment: Yeah that's part of my question. The other part is -- how can I call FuncIO inside an infinite loop without blocking, and yield properly

Comment: You can't say that `# Run FuncIO asynchronously` and at the same time you say `# Only 1 instance of FuncIO should run at a time` - it does not make sense ...
You have `asyncio.create_task`, for each detected object you can trigger an asynchronous task that runs in the background.
But if you want each detected object to run synchronously, then you have to work with locks, some global lock should handle the locks for all the background tasks.